# Where can I get a good quality video (preferably slow motion / high frame rate) of Brownian motion particles for tracking their positions?

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, data-analysis, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to analyse how good the Langevin equation fits actual experimental data by tracking the position of Brownian motion particles from video footage. However, I was unable to get my hands on a video with a frame rate and magnification high enough for analysis.

Comment: I take it making your own footage of Brownian motion is out of the question?

Comment: It is possible. However, it would take a substantial amount of effort and time to acquire a high-speed camera and build a setup where I attach that to a microscope.

Comment: I'm pretty sure neither Brown nor later Einstein had access to a high speed camera. But [this YT video seems pretty clear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSe3TFLYcO8) (and the author seems willing to share hi-res version, as per comments).

Comment: @KyleKanos Exactly! Neither of them had access to a high-speed camera. That makes it even more important to do an analysis using one and look at how good their theory fits experimental data. PS: Thanks for the video link.